# Using Desktop Shortcut Icons with Unity Workspaces

Tags: unity, workspaces, shortcuts

I have been using 14.04 for some while and have created a number of desktop shortcuts to websites and folders, in addition to the launcher shortcuts for applications.

I have recently tried to use workspaces to separate work and home activities but have been unable to create different shortcuts in different workspaces.  Even worse, when I apply different backgrounds to each workspace to make place tracking easier, I lose the shortcuts entirely.

Is there anything I can do about this, or am I forced to use the Launcher as my only route to shortcuts if I want to use distinguishable workspaces?

Any help appreciated.

Bob

Comment: I presume by _apply different backgrounds to each workspace_, you mean that you installed some app to do this? It sounds like it is most likely taking over drawing of the background from the file manager. And no, you cannot set a different background per workspace, nor different icons on the background per workspace, for the standard file manager.

Comment: You can however create a separate user, and switch between users to separate work and personal activities and data, if you wish.